# Class Property, Gettable and settable internally, but only gettable externally

Tags: c#, class, properties

I realise that this may be something really basic, but I'm not sure about the best practice to achieve the following.

I have the following class with a string property `myString`:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string myString
    {
        get {
            return myString;
        }
    }

    public void AFunction()
    {
        // Set the string within a function
        this.myString = "New Value"; // Error because the property is read-only
    }
}
```

I wish the following to be true for the `myString` property:

- Settable internally
- Gettable internally
- NOT settable externally
- Gettable externally

So I wish to be able to set the variable `myString` within the class and make its value read-only from outside of the class.

Is there a way to achieve this without the use of a separate get and set function and making the `myString` property private, like so:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private string myString { get; set; }

    public void SetString()
    {
        // Set string from within the class
        this.myString = "New Value";
    } 

    public string GetString()
    {
        // Return the string
        return this.myString;
    }
}
```

The above example allows me to set the variable internally, but not have read-only access to the actual property `myString` from outside of the class.

I tried `protected` but this doesn't make the value accessible from the outside.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can allow the setter only for the class members, usually constructor:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string myString { get; private set; }
}
```

Or you can allow setter within internal/assembly memebers:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string myString { get; internal set; }
}
```

The getter will be public.

Answer (score 12):

It sounds like you just want:

```
public string MyString { get; private set; }
```

That's a property with a public getter and a private setter.

No need for extra methods at all.

(Note that the use of the word "internally" is potentially confusing here, given the specific meaning of the keyword `internal` within C#.)

Answer (score 3):

You can specify access modifiers on the get and set, for example:

```
public string MyString
{
    get;
    private set;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public string myString { get; private set; }
```

Comment: This will cause a stack overflow as the get/set simply calls itself over and over again. You need to have it access a differently named backing field.

Comment: I already updated it - you didn't refresh page. At first didn't notice the original bug in @Coulton's code

Comment: Sorry for the bad timing! +1